# Nativescript: add icon and specify name

Tags: icons, nativescript, nativescript-cli, nativescript-vue

How would i add a custom icon with a given name to my nativescript project using the `tns resources generate icons`-command

`$tns resources generate icons ~/myfolder/myspecialicon.png`

Say i want the command to place the icon(s) in the correct folders maintaining the name `myspecialicon.xxx` instead of just overwriting the default `icon.png`?

Cheers

Lasse

Comment: At this stage, the command can only generate the app icon (`icon.png`)

Comment: Nooooo :( Haha.
So the solution is manually adding icons?

Comment: Or use a third-party tool :)  https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher

Comment: Thanks man. Guess you still have to merge the content of the folders manually or via the command-line?

Answer (score 4):

That only generates the app icon. To generate other icons (and other image assets, really) I recommend the online tool http://images.nativescript.rocks/.

It generates assets for both Android and iOS. All you have to do is grab the result and merge it into your project's `App_Resources`. I know it is not ideal but it's the best workflow I found so far.